# Generate missing javadoc with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc, gradle-plugin

With the [`maven-javadoc-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) it's possible to generate missing javadoc with the goals `fix` and `test-fix`.

While browsing the [gradle javadoc documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html) I can't find an option to generate missing docs.

So my question is: Is it possible to generate missing javadoc with gradle?

Comment: That plugin only implements the html generation part. You could maybe use a linter plugin to show you all the places that require them (e.g. https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1176 / https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=sonarlint)

Comment: The IDE I use (IntelliJ) is already showing a bunch of warning, so an extra linter plugin only for the purpose of listing missing docs seems a bit much. There is something like [`fix docs`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html#fix-javadoc), but this seems to only work for one class at a time.

Comment: But you can configure the linter to fail the build so that developers have to add them, it's manual but results in similar code to full automation. Alternatively, maybe you can add a maven config that just runs the doc fixing. You can probably run maven via a gradle exec task

Comment: The latter also came to my mind. Whether invoking maven from gradle or directly is not that big difference.